# Map.contains with a super-type of key type

Tags: scala, collections

I have a case where

```
trait EventLike
trait Event extends EventLike

trait API {
  private var map = Map.empty[Event, Any]

  def contains(e: EventLike): Boolean = map.contains(e)
}
```

This doesn't work because of the invariance in the map's key type:

```
<console>:58: error: type mismatch;
 found   : EventLike
 required: Event
             def contains(e: EventLike): Boolean = map.contains(e)
                                                                ^
```

What is a good work-around with minimum performance penalty. That is, I specifically don't want to introduce this terrible thing:

```
  def contains(e: EventLike): Boolean = e match {
    case e1: Event => map.contains(e1)
    case _ => false
  }
```

Is there a different `Map` implementation (may be mutable as this is thread local) I could use?

Comment: Why not add a more specific contains method on API for events?

Comment: @SeanVieira because the call site usually deals with opaque `EventLike` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your map as `Map[EventLike, Any]`:

```
trait API {
  private var map = Map.empty[EventLike, Any]
  def contains(e: EventLike): Boolean = map.contains(e)

  def add(e:Event): Unit = {
    map += (e -> ???)
  }
}
```

You can still populate your map with `Event` keys only, while searching both `Event` and `EventLike`.

**UPD**

If you don't mind using Java mutable collections, you can use `HashMap`, that accepts any object as argument of contains regardless of the type parameters of the map:

```
trait API {
  private val map = new java.util.HashMap[Event, Any]
  def contains(e: EventLike): Boolean = map.containsKey(e)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just moves the pattern match to the point where I want to retrieve `Event` instances from the map...

Comment: @0__ you didn't specify that you need to retrieve keys of your map as `Event` in your question.

Comment: Good point with the HashMap. I'll check its speed against Scala collections, it might indeed be a good option here.

Answer (score 0):

`EventLike` is a supertype of `Event`, so this would not work even if the `Map`'s key type were covariant.

You basically want to check whether `EventLike` is an `Event`, and you can only do this at runtime, either with your solution or with something like

```
def contains(e: EventLike): Boolean =
  e.isInstanceOf[Event] && map.contains(e.asInstanceOf[Event]
```

Wouldn't a static type check work in your case?

```
def contains(e: Event): Boolean = map.contains(e)
```

Comment: Note that the overloading is wrong, because the method is resolved at compile time, not dispatched based on runtime type. You can check this with `val e: EventLike = new Event {}`